# connecting to remote mongodb with nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express

i have a remote mongo server and i want to connect to that with nodejs . i tried connecting directly with mongo shell and it was ok ... but i cant connect to that mongodb server in nodejs ..
the mongo command for connection :

`mongo --host 192.168.10.33 --port 27017 -u mohammad -p "mypassw@12"  --authenticationDatabase=access`

i only want to convert that command into nodejs connection config..
something like:

`uri = mongodb://mohammad:mypassw@12@192.168.10.33:27017/"`

Comment: Here is the mongodb documentation:
https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/connection-string/

Answer (score 1):

The URI should be encoded

```
uri = "mongodb://mohammad:mypassw%4012@192.168.10.33:27017/access"

mongo.connect(uri, { useNewUrlParser: true }, (err, db) => {});
```

Comment: you need the `access` db at the end or it will authenticate agains `admin` and error out.

Comment: i tried that and it says ```UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: MongoError: Authentication failed```

Comment: and i also tried ``` .... :27017/access and  .... :27017/mydbname ``` but none of them worked

Comment: Might be a password issue.

Comment: replacing @ with %40  isn't enough? i'm new to js is it ok to use %40 encoding in simple string ? like "mypassw%4012"

Answer (score 1):

Connecting to a remote Mongo can sometimes be tricky , mongoose can help a great lot with connecting to your remote db . The code below should be able to do the trick and connect .

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.set('useFindAndModify', false);
const uri = "mongodb+srv://user:pass@clusterName.d4zrk.mongodb.net/databaseName?retryWrites=true&w=majority";

mongoose.connect(uri, { useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true })

const db = mongoose.connection

db.on('error', (err) => {
    console.log(err)
})
db.once('open', () => {
    console.log('Database Connection Established!')
})
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess the issue might be with your password, it looks like to contains a special character that is used by the mongodb driver to separate the credentials from the host:

`mongodb://[username:password@]host1[:port1][,...hostN[:portN]][/[defaultauthdb][?options]]`

If you have a @ in your password, you have to apply an [percent encoding](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-2.1) it by adding a % character.

Here is the list of character to encode according to [mongodb driver documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/connection-string/): : / ? # [ ] @

Comment: i tried bellow, url but it's still not working ..```url = "mongodb://mohammad:mypassw%4012@192.168.10.33:27017/mydbname"```